# Grant privileges to specific database for the user

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, privileges

I am learning oracle and PL/SQL. I have created a database called "PRACTICE" and created a user called "MITHRA" by connecting as a SYS.

My question is i want to grant privileges to the user "MITHRA" for the specific database "PRACTICE". The user "MITHRA" can able to do all activities like create, drop, alter etc.. only in "PRACTICE" database.

Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean that you created a database named "PRACTICE"?  It doesn't sound like you're using "database" in the Oracle sense of the word.  Perhaps you created a schema named "PRACTICE"?  Or perhaps you are using 12.1 despite your 11g tag and you mean that you created a CDB in a PDB?

Comment: Are you sure you mean database and not a schema?

Comment: I am sorry, i don't know what exactly in oracle sense because i just started learning oracle. But to be more specific i have created a (schema/database) using the command "create database PRACTICE". sys user will have all privileges but i have created another user "MITHRA" and i want to give privileges to that user only for the database/schema  PRACTICE.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle can only host one database so what you are asking for will essentially grant root privileges to this user, including drop database. This should be avoided on production from obvious reasons.

So in order to grant full access to user `mithra`:

Connect as sys and run the following command -

```
Grant dba to mithra;
```

That should give the user mithra all possible privileges for that database.
You can also use the grant command the grant any distinct privileges.

Comment: Why `dba`? Why not `all privileges`? Or, why not something else. OP wants to restrict the user to connect to other databases. How does granting `dba` privilege answers OP's question?

Comment: OP wants to allow user to do all activities, the DBA role is the quickest way to achieve that. Furthermore, the DBA role in Oracle is Database specific, and so will not allow any operations on other databases. What is the difference between the DBA role and granting all privileges?

Comment: "*and so will not allow any operations on other databases*" Granting privileges has nothing to do with stopping a user to connect to other database. All the grants are limited to an instance and not across other instances.

Comment: Then you should probably mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure that we speak in the same terms.
Is the "PRACTICE" database or schema? If it is DATABASE then you should grant DBA, if it is schema then Oracle does not have statements to grant rights to schemas (only system and object priveleges). Reading your question makes me think that you come from MSSQL where you can grant to a specific user gratns to specific database, in Oracle it is a little bit different - to make an analogy - you do not have databases but schemas.

Comment: I am sorry, i don't know what exactly in oracle sense because i just started learning oracle. But to be more specific i have created a (schema/database) using the command "create database PRACTICE". sys user will have all privileges but i have created another user "MITHRA" and i want to give privileges to that user only for the database/schema PRACTICE.

Comment: Which DB version are you using? If it is 12 you should "grant sysdba to mitra" Not sure about previous versions but I think Oracle 11 also has "sysdba" privilege, if not you will have grant DBA,